# Google Checkout And Node

Tags: node.js, android-pay

Is There A Pre Existing Node.js Module For Using Google Wallet/Checkout So I Don't Have To Make The JWTs Myself But Just Plugin The Product Info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these: A Google Checkout API implementation for node.js

Github page: https://github.com/wankdanker/node-google-checkout

Npm page: https://npmjs.org/package/google-checkout

Hope it fits your needs.

Comment: According to the npm page: "This module is under heavy development and is not ready for production use."
The GitHub page is different: "This API is currently working in the sandbox environment. I am working on documentation."
The version is 0.0.4 and was last updated 2 years ago.
So, what do you make of it? Is it of any use?

Answer (score 0):

No it is no longer maintained as Google moved on to Google Wallet instead of Google checkout.

Have a look at this link[node-google-checkout](https://github.com/wankdanker/node-google-checkout)